# Why does upload_from_file Google Cloud Storage Function Throws timeout error?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created a function that works for me, It uploads a file to Google Cloud Storage.

The problem is when my friend tries to upload the same file to the same bucket using the same code from his local machine, he gets **timeout error**. His internet is very good and he should be able to upload the file with no problems within his connections.

Any idea why is this happening?

```py
def upload_to_cloud(file_path):
    """
        saves a file in the google storage. As Google requires audio files greater than 60 seconds to be saved on cloud before processing
        It always saves in 'audio-files-bucket' (folder)
        Input:
            Path of file to be saved
        Output:
            URI of the saved file
    """
    print("Uploading to cloud...")
    client = storage.Client().from_service_account_json(KEY_PATH)
    bucket = client.get_bucket('audio-files-bucket')
    file_name = str(file_path).split('\\')[-1]
    print(file_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    blob.upload_from_file(f)
    f.close()
    print("uploaded at: ", "gs://audio-files-bucket/{}".format(file_name))
    return "gs://audio-files-bucket/{}".format(file_name)
```

It throughs the timeout exception in **upload_from_file(f)** line.

We tried to use upload_from_filename function, but the same error still occurs.

Comment: Does your friend have set up the same environment as you? i.e. he have the json key for the same service account, he is trying to upload the same file as you, he have a folder named 'rb' in the same path as you?

Comment: @Chris32 He has the same key yes. 
Trying the same file, it is 12.5 MB. The rb stands for read binary not a folder. The file path is passed as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Raamy. Would be interesting to know more differences between both environments i.e. different SO? if this is the case (i.e. you using windows and he using linux to run the command) Can your frind please include the print of the file_name variable please? It looks like he's getting a lot of file at once since the timeout for uploads it's 60 seconds and for 12.5 mb it should be possible with an internet connection of arround 2Mbps

Comment: @Chris32 Sorry for the late reply we were still experimenting. The problem is solved by **reducing the default chunk size** of the storage blob. And it worked with him. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is solved by reducing the chunk size of the blob. The code changed to be:

```py
def upload_to_cloud(file_path):
    """
        saves a file in the google storage. As Google requires audio files greater than 60 seconds to be saved on cloud before processing
        It always saves in 'audio-files-bucket' (folder)
        Input:
            Path of file to be saved
        Output:
            URI of the saved file
    """
    print("Uploading to cloud...")
    client = storage.Client().from_service_account_json(KEY_PATH)
    bucket = client.get_bucket('audio-files-bucket')
    file_name = str(file_path).split('\\')[-1]
    print(file_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)

    ## For slow upload speed
    storage.blob._DEFAULT_CHUNKSIZE = 2097152 # 1024 * 1024 B * 2 = 2 MB
    storage.blob._MAX_MULTIPART_SIZE = 2097152 # 2 MB

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        blob.upload_from_file(f)
    print("uploaded at: ", "gs://audio-files-bucket/{}".format(file_name))
    return "gs://audio-files-bucket/{}".format(file_name)
```

Comment: How can we use this if there are 1M blobs of 100KB each? I am facing timeouts like 4 out of 10 times while passing 1M objects to the upload function.

Comment: @johnmich sorry for my late reply. Unfortunately I am not able to help you. did you reach out a solution for your case?

Comment: @Ramyy I have not found a solution yet, I will try to use the raw storage API using the request module instead of using the official google-cloud-storage package.

Answer (score 11):

Now, you can add a custom timeout with blob as this [PR](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/pull/185/commits) is merged, default is 60 seconds. So, if your internet connection is slow, you can add a custom timeout for the upload operation.

```
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
  
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name, timeout=300)

    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )
```

Comment: 300 seconds worked for me to upload 87MB on a relatively fast internet connection. (13 MBit/sec download and 8 MBit/sec upload). I wonder that it might not be just the internet speed but some throttling at Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_retry = retry.Retry(deadline=500)

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(storage_file)
blob.upload_from_filename(local_file, retry=my_retry)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: And, in this case, why do you prefer this above the existing answers, which have been validated by the community?