# Issues using Scrapy with Google Cloud Storage as a feed export

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy, google-cloud-storage, urllib3

I am using GCS as a feed export on Scrapy as per the [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html). What is strange is that it does work some of the time.

But other times it will fail at the point of upload and the only thing I can see that is different is it was trying to upload more data. Having said that, it still failed with a ~60Mb upload which makes me question whether scale of data is really an issue here. Could someone explain whether this is an issue with my configuration or perhaps with Scrapy itself? The error report is below:

```
2020-12-01 23:07:26 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] ERROR: Error storing csv feed (19826 items) in: gs://instoxi_amazon/com/Ngolo/Amazon_Beauty_&_Personal_Care_Ngolo.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 987, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1034, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1003, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2361)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /upload/storage/v1/b/instoxi_amazon/o?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ABg5-Uwjc9Vs5HdgyQdhTTm0ph3N_xQIoZaAE44Oiv2MdMO6q-YhD31eRkWO6W7UNAlehUKm4FTgVv0KXq32SHmCrDU (Caused by SSLError(SSLWantWriteError(3, 'The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2361)')))
```

This is my first question so let me know if there's a better way to ask / present. Just to clarify, I have had no issues with using Python to interact with GCS outside of Scrapy. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen `The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2361)` before and it was due to Networking issues. This would also fit the fact that it happens inconsistently for you. I suggest you try another network to connect to internet if you can.

Nevertheless, I would also suggest to make sure you are using the latest version of Scrapy

Comment: Thank you, let me test with a wired connection and see if that is more reliable. And okay I have just upgraded Scrapy - google feed export is a fairly new feature so that's probably a good idea.

Comment: I was! You were correct about my internet being the issue. My upload speed was too slow for the operation. The question I've linked gave me a good solution for my problem (for anyone else that is interested): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61001454/why-does-upload-from-file-google-cloud-storage-function-throws-timeout-error